# How to create a sequential array of the sum of several variables and to lable a unique range?

Tags: ruby, arrays, range

My first question on this site... and behind him the second one)
Is it possible to somehow create a sequential array of the sum of several numbers in ruby?

there is a view:

```
n1 = 3
n2 = 8
n3 = 2
n1 + n2 + n3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]`
```

second question: Is it possible to keep track of the ranges for each variables in the creating array?

```
from previous example


n1 = [1, 2, 3] or (1..3)
n2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] or (4..11)
n3 = [12, 13] or (12..13)
```

I mean that I need to keep track of "pieces" of created array in first question, according to the values ​​of variables that were summation or take a label for n1, n2, n3 in array that must be a unique range.

schematically

```
                 n1 = 3            n2 = 8          n3 = 2
                |-----|  |----------------------|  |----|

n1 + n2 + n3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
                |_____|  |______________________|  |____|
                   n1              n2                n3
```

Life example. 
let's say we need to book an excursion. The bus has 30 seats. 
Everyone is welcome to book a seats in any quantity. Seats must be unique. Customer can buy more then one. 
So in our example, a tourist "n1" bought 3 tickets on the bus, from the first to third seats. 
second tourist "n2" bought eight seats from the fourth to the eleventh (he can not sit on the first three, as they are unique to the tourist "n1").

Maybe I thinking about bad model, but I have no practice yet.

ps: yes I am a noob and I still have a lot of questions)
thanks for answers

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here's a quick answer to your questions:

a) Yes you can:

```
numbers = [3,8,2]
sum_of_those_numbers = numbers.inject(&:+)
sequential_array = (1..sum_of_those_numbers).to_a
```

b) If your array contains numbers from smallest to biggest, then its range is going to be the first and the last element:

```
n1 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
puts n1.first
puts n1.last
range = (n1.min..n1.max)
```

even if your array doesn't contain numbers from smallest to biggest, you can find the smallest number of the array with n1.min and the biggest with n1.max.

Some of these things might be unclear to you, especially the inject method, I'd recommend you Google and read 2-3 articles on the topic, since all have different explanations and you might not be able to understand it immediately. Good luck!

Comment: ty for answers. first one is pretty useful)

Comment: Thank you, feel free to choose this as a best answer if you found it helpful.